# is it possible to debug the node js application running within a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging

is it possible to debug the node js application running within a docker container in **Visual Studio Code** ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for reply @DaveNewton, Can you please let me know the steps or some working resource. I have followed many tutorials but couldn't able to do it.

Comment: @DaveNewton I got stuck from past two days, If you know the approach, can you please tell me